# Algorithms for minimizing single-variable functions

Tags: algorithm, optimization, numerical-methods

Given a continuous, convex single-variable function that I want to minimize over a bounded interval [a,b], what options do I have? I have access to the numerical derivative, but not the analytic derivative.

This is done inside a loop that will be run an arbitrarily large number of times so it really needs to be as quick as possible. Bisection is elegant and simple, but I suspect you're missing out on efficiency by not utilizing convexity and slopes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this setting, I'd go with [Golden Section Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search).

- Convexity implies unimodality, which is needed by this method.
- Conversely, this method does not need derivatives. You can find derivatives numerically, but that's another way of saying "multiple function assessments"; might as well use these for golden-section partitions.

Comment: Very nice, and seems to come with some computational tricks to speed up. Do you have any idea how favorably this method compares to 'regular' bisection?

Comment: The first point in the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247111/is-golden-section-search-better-than-binary-search) addresses it.